# Install npm without node

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, node.js, npm

I am starting a ASP.NET Core Web Application using Visual Studio 2015 and I would like to use AngularJs2 with TypeScript editing.
In order for this to work I need to install the npm Package Manager.
I would like to install npm without node since I will not use Node.js.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: `npm` is written in JavaScript. How would you run the JavaScript code without a JavaScript runtime like Node.js?

Comment: Well, I would have expected to have some kind of package manager made by Microsoft and not to be forced to install node.js for this.

Comment: @IonutC npm isn't made by Microsoft.

Answer (score 16):

**No**, because *npm* is a program written in *JavaScript*, and without *Node* rather hard to run such programs on the server side (outside the browser).

Comment: One might be providing a "compiled" node program using something like zeit pkg which packages the node.js interpreter along with the JS code.  Then node.js is not required to run the program, but it would be nice to install npm as a standalone program.

Answer (score 8):

Simple answer to your questions is **No.**

`NPM` is a `NodeJS Package Manager` . As its name would imply, you can use it to install node programs.

This is a wiki defination of npm

> Npm is the default package manager for the JavaScript runtime environment Node.js.

So, you need to install Node.js in order to run NPM. Hope this helps. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Do you need to install *npm* or just some package manager? If anything is fine you can try some other package manager like *yarn* (I haven't tried it personally).
2. I believe *Typescript* is build on *JavaScript*, meaning you'll need *Node.js* to compile your tsc code. Unless! You want it compiled in the browser which is an ill-advised thing to do, but still possible.

Answer (score -1):

As npm stands for "Node Package Manager", i really think node is nessesary

Comment: npm started as the node package manager, but now is package manager for JavaScript.